# Grab mp3 url with REGEX

Tags: regex

I have a Drupal module to replace a text in this way:

```
Text to find:
Replace with:
```

I need to leave just the URL of the mp3. I thought something like:

```
Text to find: (previous text) (mp3 url) (subsequent text)
Replace with: /2
```

I found this for the URL of the mp3:

```
(((http://www)|(http://)|(www))[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]+)\.(mp3|MP3)
```

But I don't know what to use to match the entire text before and after.

(The module is "Feeds Tamper")

Answer (score 1):

Your regex for mp3 is a bit too complicated.

```
/(http://)?(www)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?\/=]+\.mp3/i
```

is a bit easier and shorter.

To match some text before and after that, you can use `.*`. That matches `everything 0 or more times`.

Comment: I need everything, new lines, html tags... This regex doesn't match with this: http://domain.org/download/episodes/episode%2091.mp3

Comment: Yeah, I forgot that. Sorry